# GKE Multi zone workload not being balanced to all zones

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-load-balancer

Running into an issue with my GKE cluster.

I've got a workload running on the cluster with nodes across multiple zones, however it seems since very recently (~7am 15th Feb) most (~90%) traffic is directed to only one of the three zones (eu-west2 a,b,c). I've tried disabling the zone being actively used but traffic is mostly just directed to another single zone. Zone c never has traffic, since I've been monitoring it.

I noticed this when only a 2/8 pods were handling all traffic and the others sat at idle, this did lead to a failure in the service, and I assume due to overall CPU limits being below the auto scale threshold.

[image]
[image: Load Balancer Monitoring]

Unsure if it is an issue with the 1.18.12-gke.1210 update for k8 or a config issue on my part, though my config for this particular service has not changed in ~3 months. Was going to try going down to 1.18.12-gke.1206, thought I'd ask here first if this is an issue unrelated.

Specs:

- Cluster Region: eu-west2
- Cluster Master/Node Version: Regular channel 1.18.12-gke.1210 (Updated 14th Feb)
- Load balanced with Ingress and NEG's (Session Affinity is none)
- Cloud CDN Cache
- Pod Autoscaling (0 - 40, Auto scales on CPU 80% and Memory 80%)
- Node Autoscaling (Min 1 per zone, Max 10 per zone)
- Nodes: n1-standard-4

Comment: Have you tried re-creating the Ingress object? Perhaps the update caused a disruption in the service, if this doesn't work it would be better to contact [GCP support](https://console.cloud.google.com/support) for further investigation as this might be specific to your project/cluster.

Comment: I tried rebuilding it in a separate cluster but same issue. Seems as though if only zone c is available then it'll use it fine but when a and b are also available traffic will only be directed to those. Also tried on the previous update but again same problem. But Thank you, I'll talk to support.